# PHP upload to FTP from file contents

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, ftp

While you can upload files to an FTP server with `ftp_put`, that would need a file that you want to upload. What if the contents of a file are inside a MySQL field?

How can I upload a file that lives in a MySQL BLOB field to an FTP server (so upload a file from a string containing file data instead of a file path)? I'm looking for a native solution, not a workaround. This because writing the data to a file, uploading the file, and deleting a file would take too long.

**Edit to clarify the OP's question:** I have a string variable that I want to upload to an FTP server. The quick and dirty way is to create a physical temporary file from my string variable, upload that file to the FTP server, and then delete the temporary file. But is there a way to upload the string variable directly to the FTP server without having to create a temporary file from it?

Comment: Really? Read the data from the table; write it to a file; transfer the file with FTP; delete the file.

Comment: That would be a workaround, yes. I'm looking for a native solution. No need to post a comment like that.

Comment: If the obvious answer is not appropriate you should make that clear in your question

Comment: No, I'm asking a question, and you give a workaround. For people like you I edited the question. Your comment would have been acceptable, but your 'Really?' is kind of rude.

Comment: To community, how can this be unclear if it already has an answer?

Comment: No idea, I would say my question is about as clear as it can get. Well, whatever.

Comment: @JasonMArcher Simple, because he answered himself. Your point would've been valid if the answer was coming from someone else, but answering himself only proves that his question is clear to himself, which nobody claimed not to be :-). "unclear" hear means "unclear to others" :-).

Comment: @Basaa No, your question is not "as clear as it can get". I had to read it carefully twice to understand it. Remember that people are helping you here for free, so you may want to make it easier for them to understand what you want. I edited your question and added a clarification, so you can see how to ask clearer questions. But I'm not sure if the moderators will keep my edit or reject it. Basically, you're want to upload a string variable directly to the FTP server without having to create a physical temp file.

Comment: With all due respect @RacilHilan, reading my own question (before your edit) from 1.5 years back for is as clear as it can get. Your edit makes no sense whatsoever, cause my "I'm looking for a native solution, not a workaround. This because writing the data to a file, uploading the file, and deleting a file would take too long" explanation is just as clear as your edit. So yes, my question was 'as clear as it can get'. And thanks, but I don't need an example from you how to ask questions.

Comment: @Basaa OK, I will take your criticism, no problem. Maybe I'm wrong and my edit was not clearer, I don't know (Only others can judge that, and the edit was meant for others as you don't need it because you already found an answer). However, please remember that it was not me who closed your question as **unclear what you're asking**. It was 5 other people who did that, so it was their opinion not mine. I'm actually the one who voted to reopen your question now after 1.5 year, so I'm on your side not against you. Three others voted with me too, so we need one more vote to reopen it.

Comment: @RacilHilan Thanks. Sorry for my somewhat raised comment. I'm having a bad day. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.

```
$fileContent = 'My file contents here';
$contentstream = fopen('data://text/plain,' . $fileContent, 'r');
ftp_fput($myConnection, '/path/to/my/folder/file.txt', $contentStream, FTP_BINARY);
```

Comment: No problem, happy stackoverflowing (can that be a thing now?).